# Rails Stripe uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

In the browser console I am getting this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined` but I have Stripe set everywhere I can think of.

The keys are set in `/config/initializers` and I have stripe in my gemfile.

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: Rails.application.secrets.stripe['publishable_key'],
  secret_key: Rails.application.secrets.stripe['secret_key']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

However, I don't think this is related to rails, I think it is the javascript from the Elements example.

> https://stripe.com/docs/elements

In my `/billing` view the v3 API is called using the example code.

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display form errors -->
    <div id="card-errors"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

Finally, I have the example js in my `billing.js` which is served by my `application.js` tree. I've used the dev environment key string instead of calling from .secrets just to troubleshoot the js.

```
  // Create a Stripe client
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_D9ssGoNFw0ZxeDvDE1P1btWl');

  // Create an instance of Elements
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      lineHeight: '24px',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });
```

Rails 5.0.1  +  ruby 2.3.0p0
Yes, I've restarted the server and bundle installed

UPDATE: stripe team says "if you're seeing 'Stripe is not defined' i suspect your own js is loading before Elements from Stripe is". So I suppose billing.js is running before the v3 script gets called, but not sure how to fix this

Comment: SOLVED: my asset pipeline was rendering the billing.js file before the v3 script tag could run. so i wrapped the billing.js file in a document.ready function

Comment: If you're using turbolinks, you may want to consider using "$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function{})" instead of the usual $(document).ready().